# GoogleMaps : Check if given marker position co ordinate is a road

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gmsmapview, gmsplacepicker

I have this project which uses `GMSKit`(GoogleMap kit) in iOS(ObjectiveC) and there is a requirement that some random points are to be generated near the user's current location.

I have successfully generated random points but now what I want is to generate some random points at say _**0.5kms away from the user and the random points has to fall on a road**.

I have gone through most of the stackoverflow questions and answers and referred so many other google sites which give idea about this.

Can someone help me with this issue ? I am very confused. Thanks to everyone in advance. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google's Road API for that. It has two calls that you can use to find roads near certain coordinate(s).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro

**1. Snap to roads**:

You send a path of coordinates to the API and it returns another path of consists of roads (as Google places ids) that are close to your path. This only works for a path (a list of coordinates)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

**2. Nearest roads**:

If you want to find the nearest roads to one single coordinate you can use the nearest roads call. It takes coordinate(s) as parameter and returns a list of roads that are near that point. This works with a single coordinate so it might be more useful in your case.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest

Boths calls return coordinates and google places ids for the found roads. You can then check the distance to your point to check if you are on a road. You can use these id in other Google APIs (e.g. Google Places API) to get more information on the found roads.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked I almost thought it would be an impossible task for me.